# jQuery mediaquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins, media-queries

I found the [link](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/MediaQueries) to jQuery mediaquery plugin. However when I try to click [Download (1.72)KB](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.mediaqueries.js_.zip) on that page it says Page Not Found. Whats wrong in here? Or I am clicking wrong link?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mahesh the pages already having the message
```

"The plugins site is currently in development." 
this means u need to wait more till the development 
completed for the mediaquery plugin and the file for downloading get available.

Comment: I cant believe this since its quite awkward not to get the script online just because the site is under maintenance. And if am not wrong this site is under maintenance for many months. Common jQuery  team u cant do this. "Write less, do more, but wait before"